# IsDirty name for member function of CField class

Tags: c++, mfc

What was the raionale behind having a function by the name IsDirty() in CField Class in MFC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terms "clean" and "dirty" are quite commonly used in data processing. When you receive a copy of some data structure from a persistent storage like a data base or file system, it is said to be "clean", unmodified, not touched. Once you are done with the data, the backing storage does not need to be updated for clean data.

Once you edit your copy, it gets "dirty" and the changes you made must be saved back to the persistent storage after you're done, otherwise they would be lost.